# Using Virtual Raster File Viewer of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, virtual-layer

I have created a virtual file using Build Virtual File functionality of QGIS.

Is the file linked strictly to where the raster files are stored or can it be viewed on another computer?

Comment: Can the other computer access the rasters at all?

Comment: Read the docs from https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html. It may work if your VRT is using absolute paths (RelativeToVRT=0) and another computer finds the files from the same path.